# How to avoid queries on Parse User table

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

Let's say I have a field to check if user subscribed or not on a mailing list.

I'm used to check by doing this, when I've not yet on my ParseCloud function any other reference for the concerned user BUT the objectId :

```
var query_user = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query_user.equalTo('objectId', result_wine.get('user').id);
return query_user.first().then(function(user) {
    if (user.get("subscribed_mail") === true) {
        /*
            Perform action
        */
    }
});
```

Could exists a way to avoid to make this kind of query, and get this field information without making this query ?

Can I improve in any way this query ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

Use pointers not IDs.

If when you use pointers in your Wine table as follows:

```
wine.set('user', userObject);
```

Then you simply include it in your query:

```
wineQuery.include('user');
```

Which lets you access it as so:

```
var user = wine.get('user');
if (user.get('subscribed_mail') === true) {
    // do stuff
}
```

When querying you can compare to whole objects with ease too:

```
wineQuery.equalTo('user', Parse.User.current());
```

Don't worry, Parse converts it all to super-fast ID matching in the background.